# How to mention dynamic directory path in Apache camel route

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel

I am trying to take files from different directories.  For example I have following directory Structure

`vendors/dir1/files/heelo.txt`
`vendors/dir2/files/hello2.txt`

in this there are 3 dirs:

1.vendors
2.dir1 and dir2
3.files

since 2. dir1 and dir2 is different, so I have to take it dynamically.

I have written following code:

```
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"> 
<route id="com.performancebikes.Inventory1" autoStartup="false"> 
<from uri="b2bmbFileSystem://com.a/vendors/${file:name}/files"/>
<to uri="b2bmbMailBox://com.b/Files"/>
</route> 
</routes>
```

since it is directory `${file:name}` is not working, please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **consume every file under `vendors`** you can consume files **recursively**:

```
<from uri="b2bmbFileSystem://com.a/vendors/?recursive=true"/>
<to uri="b2bmbMailBox://com.b/Files"/>
```

If it consumes the file `vendors/dir2/files/hello2.txt`, the output file will be saved under `com.b/Files/dir2/files/hello2.txt`, so it **recreates the same relative path as in the source file system**.

If you don't want to recreate the same structure, **you can flatten the output structure**:

```
<from uri="b2bmbFileSystem://com.a/vendors/?recursive=true"/>
<to uri="b2bmbMailBox://com.b/Files?flatten=true"/>
```

This comes with the risk that the same filename appears in multiple subdirectories and therefore you got a conflict in the target folder.

If you want to consume **only from the two specific directories** you can simply create two routes:

```
<from uri="b2bmbFileSystem://com.a/vendors/dir1/files/"/>
<to uri="b2bmbMailBox://com.b/Files"/>

<from uri="b2bmbFileSystem://com.a/vendors/dir2/files/"/>
<to uri="b2bmbMailBox://com.b/Files"/>
```

As long as the routes do not contain processing logic that is also multiplied, it is no problem to have multiple of them.

And even if you got processing logic, you could write simple "file collector routes" as the ones above and then build a route that consumes the directory where all files are collected and implement the logic in that route.

If you want to **consume from lots of specific directories**, you could inject a List of route-configurations in your application. A route config in YAML format could for example look like this:

```
fileConsumer:
  routes:
    - routeId: "consumer1"
      source: "/path/to/source/directory"
      target: "/path/to/target/directory"
    - routeId: "consumer2"
      source: "/path/to/other/source/directory"
      target: "/path/to/other/target/directory"
```

If you inject this as `List<RouteConfiguration>` you can iterate over it in a RouteBuilder class to create all configured routes:

```
@Override
public void configure() {
    configuration.getRoutes().forEach(this::addRouteToContext);
}

private void addRouteToContext(final RouteConfiguration routeConfiguration) throws Exception {
    String fileReaderSourceUri = [build complete endpoint URI from directory];
    String fileReaderTargetUri = [build complete endpoint URI from directory];

    this.camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from(fileReaderSourceUri)
            .routeId(routeConfiguration.getRouteId())
            .to(fileReaderTargetUri);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  I need to consume file from lots of different directories under the directory called vendors. But I am not getting that logic to iterate the sub directories in the route could you please give me that syantax for that?.

Comment: I extended my answer with a simplified example of the dynamic route creation based on configuration