# How to dynamically return a from endpoint in apache camel DSL

Tags: apache-camel

Here is my code

```
            from("google-pubsub:123:subscription1?maxMessagesPerPoll=3 & concurrentConsumers=5" ).routeId("myroute")
            .process(new ProducerProcessor())
        to("google-pubsub:123:topic1")
            ;
```

In my code above ,the from channel I want to make it generic.Basically it should be able to consume data from good-pubsub or may be from a file or from a JMS queue.Hence depending upon a parameter I want to return 
a different from channel.Something like below

```
private RouteDefinition fromChannel(String parameter) {
        if (parameter is "google" then
            return  from("google-pubsub:123:subscription1?maxMessagesPerPoll=3 & concurrentConsumers=5" )


        if (parameter is "file" then
           return   from(/my/fileFolder/)).split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming().parallelProcessing();



    }
```

I tried this but I am getting null pointer exception in the fromChannel method.Please let me know if you have better ideas.

Answer (score 0):

**Rewrite based on comment**

You can for example create a **(static) template route for every input type** and generate the routes based on a configured endpoint list.

I described such an endpoint configuration and route generation scenario in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51903207/8035582).

Like this you can generate the split part for every file route and any other specialty for other route types.

All these input routes are **routing at their end to a common processing route**

```
.from(pubsubEndpoint)
    .to("direct:genericProcessingRoute")

.from(fileEndpoint)
    .split(body()
    .tokenize("\n"))
    .streaming()
    .parallelProcessing()
    .to("direct:genericProcessingRoute")

.from("direct:genericProcessingRoute")
    ... [generic processing]
    .to("google-pubsub:123:topic1")
```

The multiple input (and output) routes around a common core route is called [hexagonal architecture](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/12/05/hexagonal-architecture-natural-fit-apache-camel/) and Camel fits very well into this.

Comment: Hi Burki I am already doing that .But the chalenge is this.For GCP Pubsub and some camel component it will work.But for File component I need to do split ,then tokenize,streaming ,parallelProcessing  before I convert it to individual record and pass it to downstream flow. See the example below.How can I dynamically pass them 

from(/my/fileFolder/)).split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming().parallelProcessing();

Comment: I rewrote my answer based on your comment

Comment: Hexagonal Architecture !!  My god this is fantastic ! I did not know that it is possible to achieve this.

This is fantastic and you solved my problem ..

Thanks again Burki.

Comment: Burki this answer resolved this issue of mine

There is another issue I am facing with apache camel json component.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62204589/when-jsonpathmyclass-getjsonpathexpressions-get-true-not-working-if-jso

I have posted it 1 weeks back and still no response

Can you please provide your expert opinion about it...Thanks again and appreciated your help