# .when().jsonpath(myClass.getJsonPathExpressions().get(),true) not working if json path expression is null or empty

Tags: apache-camel

```
 from("somegcpchannel").

            .choice()
                .when().jsonpath(myClassObject.getJsonPathExpressions().get(),true)//true will suppress exception if the path does not exist"
```

The problem with this camel jsonpath component is that if myClassObject.getJsonPathExpression() is null or empty it throws an exception.Hence I am forced to put some dummy json path to get it working.

How can I first check if the myClassObject.getJsonPathExpressions() if not null only then process the json path expression.All in one statement if possible(not nested choice / when).It is weird that json path component of camel does not do the null check

Comment: Any help with jsonpath will be appreciated

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. What is `myClass`? A plain Java object that is an instance variable on your RouteBuilder class? Then `myClass.getJsonPathExpressions()` would be a "static" value that remains the same while the application is running.

Comment: My mistake.It is an object with a variable jsonPathExpression.The value can be  e.g. 
$.emp.type[?(@.name=="DEP")]

But if the variable jsonPathExpression is null/empty,Camel json component throws nullpointer exception while building the route.

To avoid this error,for null or empty value ,I have to initialize the variable to $.emp.type[?(@.json_element_that_does_not_exist  == "ZZ")] .After initializing it is all good !
Here is the code again
 .choice()
                .when().jsonpath(myClassObject.getJsonPathExpressions,true)//true will suppress exception if the path does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure Java problem. You want to use a value that is stored in an instance object of your RouteBuilder class to construct a Camel Route.

```
myClassObject.getJsonPathExpressions().get()
```

When `myClassObject.getJsonPathExpressions()` returns `null` then the following `.get()` method obviously throws a NPE. Therefore the Camel route cannot be constructed.

Sidenote: this is a static value anyway. The value returned from the object is used while constructing the route and will never change while the application is running.

Since it is a pure Java problem, you cannot use Camel to solve it. You have to solve it in Java.

The most simple solution (as you already stated) is to always provide a value. To make your Route happy, just add a method to your RouteBuilder class that returns the object value if present or a sensible default.

```
private String getJsonPathExpression() {
    if (whatever checks are needed) {
        return myClassObject.getJsonPathExpressions().get(); // value present
    } else {
        return "default JsonPath that works" // no value present
    }
}
```

And then use this method in your route instead of using the object directly

```
.when().jsonpath(getJsonPathExpression(),true)
```

This way you simply hide all the value checking stuff in the method.

Comment: Hi Burki thank you for your response.The exception is coming from the camel json path component when getJsonPathExpression() return empty.I was expecting jsonpath to return false if it is empty !! Wondering if it possible to say in camel 
--Code --
--invoke jsonpath ONLY if getjsonpathexpression() is not null
when getjsonpathexpression() is not null AND  jsonpath(getJsonPathExpression(),true)
      do THIS
otherwise
     do that;

Agreed that mine is a java problem and will go with your appraoch.Your last answer is enough to solve my problem.Thanks again Burki.Very helpful